# Solving difficult captcha using pytesseract

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am beginner at pytesseract.

I try to get the letters from those captcha images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/download (2).png'))
```

But it gives me "" as output.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to escape space and / characters. I suspect that this might be causing the issue.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program\ Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('C:\/Users\/user\/Desktop\/download\ (2).png'))
```

Comment: do not work. it gave me error. there is no problem in space in image name

Comment: There might be a problem with the way that you are passing in the path. Use python to create a file in that path and see if it will work.